# Change form destination based on radio selection

Tags: javascript, forms

I am creating a form, and giving user three options. They can select only one, based on their selection I want to send them to different page. So if they select option 1, they goto abc.html , option 2 they goto def.html etc etc

```
       <form id="account" action="somepage.php">
        <p>Select an Option</p>
          <input type="radio" name="group1" id="basic" checked="checked" />

          <input type="radio" name="group1"  id="trade" />

          <input type="radio" name="group1"  id="pro" />

          <button class="s_button_1 s_main_color_bgr" type="submit"><span class="s_text">Continue</span></button>
        </form>
```

---

Ok Edited to add new code, in fact our actual code. 
We are on a register.php page, and are offering users three levels of registration ( they can choose only one )
So the URL is www.somedomain.com/register.php

```
<form id="account">
      <div class="s_row_3 clearfix">
        <p>Registration Options: choose your account type</p>
        <label class="s_radio" for="basic">
          <input type="radio" name="group1" id="basic" checked="checked" value="basic.php" onclick="setLocation(this)"/>
          <strong>Register a Basic Account</strong>&nbsp;<a rel="prettyPhoto[ajax]" href="/infopops/basic.php?ajax=true&width=100%&height=100%"><span class="info">&nbsp;</span></a>
        </label>
        <label for="trade">
          <input type="radio" name="group1"  id="trade" value="trade.php" onclick="setLocation(this)"/>
          <strong>Register a Trade Account</strong>&nbsp;<a rel="prettyPhoto[ajax]" href="/infopops/trade.php?ajax=true&width=100%&height=100%"><span class="info">&nbsp;</span></a>
        </label></a>
        </label>
         <label for="pro">
          <input type="radio" name="group1"  id="pro" value="pro.php" onclick="setLocation(this)"/>
          <strong>Register a Pro Account</strong>&nbsp;<a rel="prettyPhoto[ajax]" href="/infopops/pro.php?ajax=true&width=100%&height=100%"><span class="info">&nbsp;</span></a>
        </label></a>
        </label>
        <br />
        <p>By creating an account you will be able to shop faster, be up to date on an order's status, and keep track of the orders you have previously made.</p>

      </div>
      <span class="clear border_ddd"></span>
      <br />
      <button class="s_button_1 s_main_color_bgr" type="submit"><span class="s_text">Continue</span></button>
    </form>
```

Js is:

```
<!--form script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
            function setLocation(element) {
            document.forms[0].action = element.value
    }
</script>
<!--//form script end-->
```

Comment: When they click on any of the radiobuttons, they immediately are taken to another page. So, why is it necessary to use radiobuttons?

Comment: @DOK - The OP only wants to change the `action` attribute, so that when the form is submitted it'll be sent to the correct location.

Comment: Are you looking to send them to a specific page when they submit the form, or when they click one of the radio buttons?

Comment: yes change form action to alternate url based on radio selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier with jQuery, but here's a basic version:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="basic" value="a.html" onclick="setLocation(this)" checked="checked" />

function setLocation(element) {
        document.forms[0].action = element.value
}
```

Comment: do i need to change <form id="account"> ? ie. get rid of the action ? I am running this now, and not getting any joy..

Comment: I had it in a doc ready function.. grr, yeah its working, for some reason if I am on page www.domain.com/index.php it gets parsed like this www.domain.com/trade.php?group1=trade.php

Comment: Edit your post and put your new HTML below your existing question.

Comment: You need to set method="post" for the form.

Comment: Sometimes you just need fresh eyeballs. :)